# Django Wizard don't save variable in sessions when go back

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I created a wizard form in django  with 8 steps and for each step I do:

```
def process_step(self, form):
     if self.steps.current == 'step1':
         ...
         self.request.session['arrangement'] = arr_code
     elif self.steps.current == 'step2':
         ...
         self.request.session['arrangement'] = arr_code
     ...

def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
     if self.steps.current == 'step1':
         arrPK = self.request.session.get('arrangement', None)
         ...
```

I used this for the back function, so when from a step i go back to the previous one I can reload data.
This works perfect for the first 3 steps, but from the forth and upper the arrPK was always null.
What can be the problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you get the answer?